# Проблема PowerShell на Python

Tags: python, powershell, shell, subprocess

Нужна помощь, не получается работать с powershell на пайтоне.
Вот код:

```
import subprocess

def execute_powershell_script(script):
    completed_process = subprocess.run(['powershell', '-command', script], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
    return completed_process.stdout

while True:
    command = input("Введите команду PowerShell: ")

    # Записать команду во временный скрипт
    script = f"{command}\n Get-Location"
    
    # Выполнить скрипт и получить результат
    result = execute_powershell_script(script)
    print(result)
```

Я выполняю команду **ls** и смотрю что нахожусь в директории **D:\project\test**
дальше выполняю **cd /** и вижу что нахожусь теперь в D:\ но если снова посмотреть на **ls** то она возвращает на изначальную директорию **D:\project\test** каждая новая команда начинается с изначальной директории. Как решить эту проблему? Мне нужно перемещаться по директориям и просматривать содержимое а у меня постоянно с изначальной папки начинает

Мучал chatGPT и он выдает: Понял, в этом случае проблема связана с тем, что каждая команда subprocess.run() выполняется в отдельном процессе, и изменения рабочей директории, сделанные в одной команде, не сохраняются для других команд. НО КАК РЕШИТЬ? НЕ ПОЛУЧАЕТСЯ

Comment: Вы каждый раз создаете новый процесс, поэтому две команды между собой никак не связаны. вас надо запустить один процесс и взаимодействовать с ним. ищите subprocess communicate. примеров должно быть много

Comment: Спасибо за ответ Sergey Tatarintsev, да изначально понял что создаются разные процессы. С subprocess communicate не совсем понятно как это работает, но постараемся глянуть что да как. Не могу найти схожие вопросы

Answer (score 0):

как вариант рассмотрите запись пути в переменную, а затем конкатенацией добавлять в скрипт, что то вроде:

```
import subprocess

path: str = ''

def execute_powershell_script(script, command):
    if 'cd' in command:
        path += command + ' & '
    completed_process = subprocess.run(['powershell', '-command', path+script], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
    return completed_process.stdout

while True:
    command = input("Введите команду PowerShell: ")

    # Записать команду во временный скрипт
    script = f"{command}\n Get-Location"
    
    # Выполнить скрипт и получить результат
    result = execute_powershell_script(script, command)
    print(result)
```

Comment: Введите команду PowerShell: cd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\project\kichinekei_balapan\gsdf.py", line 18, in <module>
    result = execute_powershell_script(script, command)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "d:\project\kichinekei_balapan\gsdf.py", line 7, in execute_powershell_script
    path += command + ' & '
    ^^^^
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'path' where it is not associated with a value